# How do I subset xts object if 'indexTZ' is deprecated?

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I was trying to subset an xts object by doing

```
irreg["T09:00/T10:00"]
```

I received the following warning message.

```
Warning message:
'indexTZ' is deprecated.
Use 'tzone' instead.
See help("Deprecated") and help("xts-deprecated").
```

I tried `help("xts-deprecated")` and nothing came back.

Question: How should I subset the xts object now, if the method I used above is deprecated?

Comment: Which version of xts are you using? I don't get any warning with this kind of filtering, except that `timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone (). `, which is not relevant (for me). If you still have an issue, add a dput of your object to the question so we have a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: This was an issue in version 0.12.0 and was fixed in 0.12-1.